# Arduino Record pulseIn

Tags: interrupt, timers, ir, pulsein

I am currently working on a project which requires me to record IR signals. (I realize there is a library available for doing this but I want to learn how to do this myself).

I tried using a simple sketch which prints out `pulseIn()` times on the Arduino, but then if I try to record them into an array, the Arduino misses the pulses happening while it is writing the timings to the array.

How can I achieve being able to record these fast pulses to the Arduino's memory without skipping some of the pulses?

Comment: I wouldn't use `pulseIn` myself because it can block for quite a while until it times out. You could use interrupts or other methods. Try reading the code for IRLib and see the techniques they use.

Comment: @NickGammon I am unsure of which file in the library records the code.

Comment: `IRLib.cpp` seems to me to be the bulk of it.

Comment: You could record the pulses first, and print them later. Storing the pulses in the array should be significantly faster than printing them.

Comment: I tried but storing them in an array is also slow. @EdgarBonet

Comment: That's really weird. Can you show the code? I'd like to take a look at the generated assembly.